# django-rest-framework login user

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have created serializers and api end points for user registration and login. Everything works till now except I cannot login when created user has no email address. If user has email address I can login by submitting either email or username, also I can register a user without an email address. This is my code:

serializers.py

```
class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    token = CharField(allow_blank=True, read_only=True)
    username = CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    email = EmailField(label='Email Address', required=False, allow_blank=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'token',
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {"password":{"write_only": True}} 
    def validate(self, data):
        user_obj = None
        email = data.get("email", None)
        username = data.get("username", None)
        password = data["password"]
        if not email and not username:
            raise ValidationError("A username or email is required to login.")
        user = User.objects.filter(
                Q(email=email) |
                Q(username=username)
            ).distinct()
        user = user.exclude(email__isnull=True).exclude(email__iexact='')
        if user.exists() and user.count() == 1:
            user_obj = user.first()
        else:
            raise ValidationError("This username/email is not valid")
        if user_obj:
            if not user_obj.check_password(password):
                raise ValidationError("Incorrect credentials, please try again")
        data["token"] = "SOME RANDOM TOKEN"
        return data
```

views.py

```
class UserLoginAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            return Response(new_data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the problematic line :

```
 user = user.exclude(email__isnull=True).exclude(email__iexact='')
```

You exclude users without email, so obviously they cannot log in.